# In darktable the lighttable recently defaulted to collapsed sidebars

Tags: software, darktable

I use darktable for my post-processing, but recently the lighttable view has defaulted to having all the sidebars collapsed. Generally speaking, I usually want them all opened up, and it used to work that way. I can't find any setting that appears to address the view state of the lighttable -- only whether modules within a sidebar are opened singly or multiples. When I open an image in the darkroom all the sidebars are open.

I'm running Debian 9 (Stretch) and darktable 2.2.1

Comment: Have you tried simply hitting "Tab" on your keyboard?

Comment: How silly. I must've hit "Tab" accidentally. Didn't know it did that. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you accidentally hit the [TAB] button on your keyboard. Hitting it again should toggle it back.

Comment: Yes, "twalberg" already pointed that out and that's absolutely what it was.

Comment: Comments should not be  used for answers.  They are subject to deletion at any time, are against the spirit of the SE networks,  and specifically addressed as not acceptable in both the guidelines here at 'Photography' and at the general SE guidelines.